# Solve $n$. $\varphi = n[\ln(\alpha) - \ln(x)]$, where $\varphi = \frac{\partial [\ln(x)]}{\partial [\ln(y)]}$.

Tags: partial-derivative

Question: Solve for $n$. $\varphi = n[\ln(\alpha) - \ln(x)]$, where $\varphi = \frac{\partial [\ln(x)]}{\partial [\ln(y)]}$.

Solution:

Eq. 1: $\varphi = n[\ln(\alpha) - \ln(x)]$

Substitute $\varphi$ from Eq. 1 to Eq. 2:

Eq. 2: $\frac{\partial [\ln(x)]}{\partial [\ln(y)]} = n[\ln(\alpha) - \ln(x)]$

I try to equate the expression with $n$ to the expression of $\varphi$ then simplify it to $n = \frac{\partial [\ln(y)]}{\partial [\ln(x)](\ln(\alpha) - \ln(x))}$. However, the equation does not make sense because there are partial derivatives, should I solve the partial derivatives first before I substitute?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Is $y$ a function of $x$ or what are we looking at?

Comment: @AEngineer. No, y is not a function of x. Both x and y are independent variables.